# Возможно ли создать игру взаимодействующею с рабочим столом в unity

Tags: unity3d, desktop

Возникла идея создать приложение которое может взаимодействовать с рабочим столом. Допустим создать в unity персонажа, прописать анимации и правила. И отображать этого персонажа на рабочем столе без окна игры. Грубо говоря игра стартует с запуском windows и на раб столе появляется персонаж с которым пользователь может взаимодействовать. Но при этом так же взаимодействовать с рабочим столом как обычно
Вопрос: возможно ли такое создать в unity? Я гуглил этот вопрос, но к сожалению ничего не нашел. Буду рад, если кто то подскажет))

Comment: @Yaroslav, я понимаю, что идея не нова и возможно не самая лучшая. Я просто хочу знать, возможно ли это реализовать с помощью unity

Comment: Тоже задаюсь таким вопросом, пока не нашол решение